# Googlesheets VLOOKUP

Tags: google-sheets

I am in need of creating a shift roster.

I have a tab on google sheet called `Shift Availability` containing the availability of staff as below (Y denotes that the employee is available)

[image]

I have another tab where I am trying to populate every cell of column 'B' with available employee names from the `Shift Availability` tab

[image]

The cell values should be a dropdown that I can choose from `Employee 1`,`Employee 2`,`Employee 3`,`Employee 4` etc based on whether they are available then.

I tried following some articles & writing a `VLOOKUP` query but not able to get this right. This is first time I am using google sheets & I've used `VLOOKUP` about twice in my career. Please can someone guide me to get this right?

The VLOOKUP at present looks as below -

```
=iferror(query(query(ShiftAvailability!A:G,"Select * where A=12/1/2022",1)),"Select Col1 where Col2='Y'")
```

**LINK** - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ERlXg8ZDqz9nAwfiaBMuFuMkG5UKQjRQDestgRnQbcI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Share a sample google-sheet.

Comment: Hello Harun - Many thanks - Here we go - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ERlXg8ZDqz9nAwfiaBMuFuMkG5UKQjRQDestgRnQbcI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this formula in C2 and apply to the entire column C:

```
=TRANSPOSE(IFNA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(ShiftAvailability!A:F),"select Col1 where Col"&MATCH(A2,ShiftAvailability!A:A,0)&"='Y'",1),))
```

Set the drop down list as follows:

- Cell range: `B2:B`
- List range: `=C2:2`

Comment: Hello Idfurw. Many thanks. I've updated the S/S with your forumula. No, I don't think this is working. Please have a look at the spreadsheet

Comment: I think it is working, please elaborate.

Comment: Yes you are right. It was a mistake at my end where I hadn't included cell F in the range & hence never saw the name employee6. 

Please can you tell me how to hide the values being displayed in columns C,D, E & so on. I don't want those values displayed. I only want to see them in the drop down list

Comment: Just create a new sheet and only set the drop down list there.

Comment: Awesome. I am very sorry. I missed adding a criterion that we should also check the sheet called "Leaves" & make sure that employee is not on leave (Y means leave) If I may request one more help, please can you help add this condition too to the query